# How can I get a line cord to stay in a broken modular jack?

Tags: connector, telephone

I have quite a few telephones. One I bought supposedly broken but I fished the jack out of the phone and found part of the connector was missing. A line cord could still snap in.

Today, I was swapping cords from my PBX and the part of the plug that keeps the cord in broke off. The cord is fine obviously but the jack is not. The only way to keep the cord in is by pinching down on it with my fingers which is impractical.

I tried duct taping them together tightly to force the wires to touch but they would only work for a few seconds or minutes. I have since removed all the duct tape. A clothespin will not fit around them.

How can I get the line cord to stay, or otherwise modify the cord or the jack to stay? I am not sure about rewiring.

This phone is useless without the jack working.

I am handy with telephone operation but not fixing wiring issues. What I envision would be either:

1. Wrapping something really, really, really tight around the cord and connector.
2. Strip the line cord, cut the connector off and somehow fuse (aka scotch tape) the four wires together
3. ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Get a replacement. FYI: This is a Q&A site about electronic design, this isn't really on-topic. That being said, I wish there were a MacGyver stackexchange...

Comment: @Bort I cannot get a replacement. Am wondering how I can modify either the cord or the jack to make them 'cooperate'. A new one seems like to much hassle anyways, I'm not sure where to buy these and I've done RJ45 crimping before and it's no fun. I don't fancy rewiring those four wires to a jack.

Comment: You only need tip and ring (two wires).  You can toss the connectors and permanently wire in the cord if you have no access to replacement parts.  But these phones are really old.  And I'm not sure if make break (pulse) dialing is even supported on some equipment.

Comment: That's a standard part, of course you can get a replacement.  Or directly wire it. Regardless, the situation is outside the intended scope of this site.

Comment: I use a toothpick, wedged tight.

Comment: Maybe you can put a small wire tie around it to hold it. They are ubiquitously used to hold wires in place, illegally defeat safety interlocks, disable circuit breakers, and so on.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, that reminds me, I must remember to chain up the fire extinguishers, people keep stealing them! :)

Answer (score 1):

Phones normally connect to the wall using an [RJ11](https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/connectors/networking/rj11-telephone/http://) plug / jack combination.  [POTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) phone equipment needs one pair of wires normally referred to as "tip & ring".  There is a diagram of which of the 4 RJ11 wires make up the first "tip & ring" pair in the 1st link above.